# Is it possible to add values to a custom slot type in Lambda ASK code?

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, slots

I am making a custom slot type that will be different for each skill user based on a certain list of their products. Is there a way to define an empty slot called "userProducts" and then populate it in my NodeJS code with Alexa Skills kit?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same thing, but unfortunately there isn't a way to update the list of slot values at runtime. However, the values that Alexa will fill a slot with aren't limited to the sample values that you've entered so you could try to match the given value to your list at runtime and keep asking the user what they want until you get an acceptable value.

> Note that a custom slot type is not the equivalent of an enumeration. Values outside the list are still returned if recognized by the spoken language understanding system. Although input to a custom slot type is weighted towards the values in the list, it is not constrained to just the items on the list. [Define the Interaction Model in JSON and Text](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/defining-the-voice-interface)